# Angular Meteor Socially Tutorial - Google Maps not loading - MissingKeyMapError

Tags: meteor, angular

I am getting this error when trying to load google maps

> Google Maps API error: MissingKeyMapError

I am accessing the application on my localhost http://localhost:3000/
After googling I noticed that an API key needs to be passed to resolve this error, but how do I pass this key? I don't see any attributes related to this key for sebm tag.

Party-detail.html has the following:

```
  <sebm-google-map
        [latitude]="lat || centerLat"
        [longitude]="lng || centerLng"
        [zoom]="8"
        (mapClick)="mapClicked($event)">
   <sebm-google-map-marker
          *ngIf="lat && lng"
          [latitude]="lat"
          [longitude]="lng">
   </sebm-google-map-marker>
  </sebm-google-map>
```

Answer (score 0):

You may place following the script in your index.html file

```
 <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=YOUR_GOOGLE_MAPS_API_KEY_HERE"></script>
```

before

```
  <script src="build/js/app.bundle.js"></script>
```

and you may manage an api key form

```
 https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/
```